# Catch empty list exeption in Haskell (head)

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function that gets the index of the first even number from a list. The list I get may or may not contain even numbers, and I'd like to return -1 if there are no even numbers in the list. The list can be infinite.

I wrote this

```
posicPrimerPar'' :: [Int] -> Int
posicPrimerPar'' a = fromJust (elemIndex (head (filter (even) a)) a)
```

I could do something like:

```
posicPrimerPar' :: [Int] -> Int
posicPrimerPar' a = case length evens of
  0 -> -1;
  n -> fromJust elemIndex (head evens) a
  where evens = filter (even) a
```

But as you can see, this is not the most efficient way of doing it. A list `[1..100000]` contains a lot of even numbers, and I just need the first one. I need Haskell's laziness, so I need to ask for the head right there, but head throws an empty list exception when the list is empty (i.e. there are no even numbers in the list). I cannot find the Haskell equivalent of Python's `try: ... except: ...`. All I could find regarding exceptions were IO related. What I need is `except Prelude.head = -1` or something like that.

Comment: Haskell is lazy, so `evens` will *not* be fully evaluated. The problematic part is the `length evens` which is not necessary.

Comment: Counterpoint: mixing index-based programming and lists is a code smell. Are you sure you need the index at all? Perhaps your enclosing algorithm can be reworked to avoid it.

Comment: Note that returning `-1` in Haskell is bad style, since the caller can easily forget to check for that special value. In some other languages with poor types one is forced to do that but in Haskell (and plenty of other languages) one can return `Maybe Int`, use `Nothing` for the "not found" special value, and so force the caller to properly handle the exceptional case.

Comment: @chi unfortunately, I must return -1 if not even numbers are found. It's part of the assignment.

Comment: @DanielWagner yep, it's an assignment and I must return the index, or -1 in case no even numbers are found, not much of a choice there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haskell is lazy, so `evens` will *not* be fully evaluated. The problematic part is the `length evens` which is not necessary. You can check with [**`null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null), or with *pattern matching*. For example:

```
import Data.List(findIndex)

posicPrimerPar' :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
posicPrimerPar' [] = Nothing
posicPrimerPar' xs = findIndex even xs
```

for [**`findIndex :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:findIndex), you however do not need to take into account the empty list, since it already considers this.

or we can return `-1` in case there is no such item:

```
import Data.List(findIndex)
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

posicPrimerPar' :: [Int] -> Int
posicPrimerPar' = fromMaybe (-1) . findIndex even
```

Comment: @chi: yes, that is written below that code fragment.

Comment: Thanks, this works. May I ask if there's a way to catch exceptions in Haskell though? Provided that in another context there's no function like findIndex and and the desired function throws an exception instead of Nothing (like head on an empty list).

Comment: Catching exceptions is fraught with peril. Experts can do it, but I've been a Haskell hobbyist for about a decade and still had no reason to catch a single exception. It's not the kind of thing you'll need to do in an introductory course.